# Display custom error message in pdf thumbnail creation - PHP - Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am running Apache with PHP5 in my windows PC. I have successfully configured Ghostscript and Image magic. I have a script to generate pdf thumbnail as follows;

```
<?php
$file = 'test.pdf';
$page = 1;
$pdfpage = $page - 1;
$nh = 200;
$nw = 200;

$im = new imagick(realpath($file)."[$pdfpage]");
$im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setCompressionQuality(100);
$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$im->sampleImage($nw,$nh);
$im->writeImage("test.jpg");
echo "true";
?>
```

This works great for me. The script generates a page thumbnail corresponding to `$page` variable. But this wont work if the page number exceeds available number of pages in the document. What I want is to display or echo `"false"` if the input variable exceeds available number of pages in the PDF file or if the imagick function feel some difficulty to run. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In **theory**, you can use the `%n` variable to the `-format` parameter to the `identify` command to find the number of pages ('frames', 'images') of a given file, including PDF, **before** you run your main command. This way you can use the result to fill the correct value into your main command, so you don't get the error message in the first place:

```
identify -format %n some.pdf
```

In **practice**, this can be ***extremely slow*** (because ImageMagick seems to render the complete PDF virtually first to count the pages).

Therefor, my advice is to use an external commandline tool to get the number of PDF pages: `pdfinfo`. This tool is specialized on PDF files, and it knows where to look for this info (because this number is part of the required metadata of any PDF file, pdfinfo doesn't need to render each and every page first before it can spit out the info):

```
pdfinfo some.pdf | grep Pages:
pdfinfo some.pdf | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'
```

Just so you see the different performance levels of the two commands, I did run it against the file that holds the official ISO 32000 spec for PDF-1.7:

```
time identify  -format %n ~/Downloads/PDF32000_2008.pdf 
756

real  0m51.902s
user  0m50.133s
sys   0m1.090s


time pdfinfo ~/Downloads/PDF32000_2008.pdf | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'
756

real  0m0.138s
user  0m0.041s
sys   0m0.016s
```

So the performance difference for a 756-page PDF document is 51.9 seconds vs. 0.138 seconds (or 376:1).

I also tested with a 12-page PDF file. Here the performance ratio is 31:1. A 1-page PDF shows
10:1 -- all in favor of `pdfinfo`.

Old IT mantra: **'Use the right tool for the job...'**

Answer (score 0):

```
$file        = 'test.pdf';
$total_pages = 1; // Probably should already know pages but if you don't, you can find out with imagick
$pdfpage     = $page - 1;
$nh          = 200;
$nw          = 200;

try {
    for($current_page = $total_pages; $current_page >= 0;$current_page--) {
        $im = new imagick(realpath($file)."[$pdfpage]");
        $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
        $im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
        $im->sampleImage($nw,$nh);
        $im->writeImage("test.jpg");
        if ($im->haspreviousimage()) { // Imagick reads pages in reverse order, thats why we're getting the previous image
            $im->previousimage();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    die('ImagickException ' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Exception ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```